# how to create a container the full width of another container

Tags: html, css

I am creating a login, and want to add a container to another container. One container is light blue and the other one is dark blue. [This is a screen shot of what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed7SR.png)

I want to be able to have the dark blue container the full width of the other container, and the height to be bigger than what it currently is. This is the structure of the html below:

```
 <div class="container">
  <a href="../index.html">
         <img id="logologin" src="../img/logo1.png" alt="logo"/>
    </a>
    <div class="card card-container">
    <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
    <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">  <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>

        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
            <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
            <label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></label>
            <label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required></label>
            <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
            <div class="link"> <a href="register4.php"> Forgot Password?
        </a></div> 
        </form><!-- /form -->

        <div class="forgot-password">
            Don't have an account? <a href="register4.php"> Create an account
        </a>
    </div><!-- /forgot-password -->

</div><!-- /card-container -->

  </div><!-- /container -->
```

This is the css I have for the dark blue container I am trying to build

```
.forgot-password {
color: #848585;
font-size:14px;
background-color: #5967b9;
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance - js fiddle containing all code https://jsfiddle.net/68t0t1jt/

Comment: Please provide all CSS that is relevant for this

Comment: can you provide snippet or fiddle with the current look code and the relevant CSS, not only a part of it

Comment: wild guess here ist that .card-container ( or .card ) has a padding that defines the gap between the container and its children. this would to have to be changed to reach your goal. but without the complete code its hard to tell

Comment: @CalvinNunes This is a basic version of what it looks like minus fonts, button css etc https://jsfiddle.net/68t0t1jt/

Comment: @Dirk i added a fiddle, if you want you can have a look, that provides all the code

Comment: @Naomi provided a fiddle which you can see in comments and at the bottom of question. This contains all the code

Comment: ok, yes so if you remove the padding from the .card-container.card and reapply it to its children ( .form-signin) you can have .forgot-password to be 100% width of its parent

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/68t0t1jt/1/

Comment: @Dirk I changed the padding to its child and then added the width to 100% on .forgot-password and it didn't change anything

Comment: @cc111 see my updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/68t0t1jt/1/

Comment: @Dirk Thank you so much! This worked wonders, if you want to add it as an answers so I can mark it right, feel free. Otherwise, thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle : jsfiddle.net/68t0t1jt/1

As described in the comments, you just have to remove the padding from .card-container.card and reapply it to .form-signin

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the card-container padding, that is the class with padding that is making impossible to inside elements to have the full width with this:

```
.card-container{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

then you can add the padding or margin to the form element, to make it's contents back to the center:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" style="padding: 40px 40px;">
```

and then you use this `forgot-password` class:

```
.forgot-password {
    color: #848585;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color: #5967b9;
    width: 100%;
  //height: 75px --if you want to change height, just uncomment
}
```

very basic fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6L84ycr4/  
Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks, Dirk created a fiddle doing the same thing, but thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try:

```
<div class="container" style="height: inherit;" >
```

or height:100%